# Reading wav file in C++ crashes only in release (works fine in debug)

Tags: c++, audio

I'm reading a wav file in C++ that only crashes when running the program in release mode.

I get this error message:

> error for object 0x7fc7b3d2b1f8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed." or "Segmentation fault: 11`

When running the program in debug mode it can read and play the wav file just fine.

```
void WaveFormat::Load(std::string filename) {
std::ifstream file(filename, std::ifstream::binary);
if (file.good()) {
    file.read(chunkID, WaveFormat::NUM_CHARS);
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&chunkSize),
              sizeof(unsigned int));

    file.read(format, WaveFormat::NUM_CHARS);
    file.read(subChunkID, WaveFormat::NUM_CHARS);
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&subChunkSize),
              sizeof(unsigned int));

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&audioFormat),
              sizeof(unsigned short));

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&numChannels),
              sizeof(unsigned short));

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&sampleRate),
              sizeof(unsigned int));

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&byteRate),
              sizeof(unsigned int));

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&blockAlign),
              sizeof(unsigned short));

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&bitsPerSample),
              sizeof(unsigned short));
    do 
    {
        file.read(subChunk2ID, WaveFormat::NUM_CHARS);
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&subChunk2Size),
                  sizeof(unsigned int));

        data = new char[subChunk2Size];
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(data), subChunk2Size);
    } 
    while (strncmp(subChunk2ID, "data", 4) != 0);
    file.close();
}
```

}

The header file:

```
struct WaveFormat
{
public:
    static const unsigned short NUM_CHARS = 4;

public:
    WaveFormat() : data(nullptr) {
    }
    ~WaveFormat() {
        delete[] data;
    }

    void Load(std::string filename);

    char chunkID[NUM_CHARS];
    unsigned int chunkSize;
    char format[NUM_CHARS];
    char subChunkID[NUM_CHARS];
    unsigned int subChunkSize;
    unsigned short audioFormat;
    unsigned short numChannels;
    unsigned int sampleRate;
    unsigned int byteRate;
    unsigned short blockAlign;
    unsigned short bitsPerSample;
    char subChunk2ID[NUM_CHARS];
    unsigned int subChunk2Size;
    char* data;
};
```

If I comment out the do...while the program no longer crashes.

Comment: Try increasing the compiler optimization level in the debugger config and rerunning. Repeat until you get the same crash. Hopefully the optimizer won't strip out and re-order too much to get a good look at where the failure occurs.

Comment: `data = new char[subChunk2Size];` inside a loop and no deallocation in sight... is something relevant missing in this sample?

Comment: Added the header file

Comment: I see. However, if you're going to have that do..while loop there, there's a potential for it to run more than once. In that case you will leak all the character arrays you allocate with `data = new char[subChunk2Size];` other than the one from the last iteration. Not that this should cause a segfault, but it's a bad bad bug anyway. It would be nice to get a stacktrace even from a release build... Or maybe try valgrind and see what it tells you. | Checking that all the reads succeed wouldn't be a bad idea either.

Comment: How do I get the stacktrace from a release build?